# How to parse a string to an Object

Tags: javascript

I have a string `"host1:23,host2:24"` and I would like to parse an object like : `[{host:host1,port:23},{host:host2,port:24}]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Then split it at the comma first, the parts at the colon each, and then create an object from it, and insert it into an array … Make an _attempt_ to try and solve the problem yourself first of all, and show us that! A mere “I want” is not a proper way to ask a question here.

Comment: You have a custom data format.  There's no built-in tool to use your custom data format.  You'll need to write code and attempt to build the logic to parse it.  If, during that attempt, you encounter a specific problem then we can help with that.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback I'll keep that in mind and improve my self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live Demo [here](https://runkit.com/embed/nork58z7c49v):

[image]

```js
const str = "host1:23,host2:24";
const items = str.split(',');
let output = [];
items.forEach(item =>  {
    entries = item.split(':');
    output.push({host: entries[0], port: parseInt(entries[1])});
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below:

```
let input = "host1:23,host2:24";
let data = input.split(',');
let output = [];
data.map(function (item) {
     let temp_dict = {};
     let obj = item.split(':');
     temp_dict['host'] = obj[0];
     temp_dict['port'] = obj[1];
     output.push(temp_dict);
});
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

split the string by "," then use `reduce` on split string array and generate you desired array:

```
const str = "host1:23,host2:24"

const arr = str.split(',')

let obj = arr.reduce((acc, currItem) => {

  const [host, port] = currItem.split(":")

  return [...acc, {host, port: Number(port)}]

}, [])

console.log(obj)
```